# implicit paramters vs TypeTag when to use and why

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Scala suffers **type erasure**, but it also introduces **TypeTag** to overcome type erasure problem.

Sometimes we can use **implicit parameters**(or even value paramters are enough) to solve the same problem that we countered.

For exammple:

```
// implicit paramters
def getKindName[T](implicit x: T): String = {
      x match {
        case _: People => "Mammals"
        case _: Sparrow => "Birds"
        case _: Shark => "Fishes"
        case _: Crocodile => "Reptiles"
        case _ => ???
      }
}

// TypeTag
def getKindName[T: TypeTag]: String = {
    typeOf[T] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[People] => "Mammals"
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Sparrow] => "Birds"
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Shark] => "Fishes"
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Crocodile] => "Reptiles"
      case _ => ???
    }
}
```

So my question are:

- why and when use Type Tag and implicit paramters ?
- what are the differences of **perfomance** between Type Tag and implicit paramters?

If you could give me a link of doc in scala to prove your opinion, it is perfect. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. Implicit parameters allow you to implicitly pass parameters to methods. TypeTag provide type information at run-time to get around type erasure.

Comment: yes, I understand what you mean. But I am wondering if I can use implicit paramters to silve the type erasure, why should I use TypeTag ?

Comment: Scala doesn't "use" type erasure. More like it suffers from type erasure because it is a JVM language. The use of implicits has no effect on type erasure. The two are unrelated.

Comment: @LeylaLee You use type tag in the cases where you really need information on what type `T` really is. Since the JVM erases generic types at compile time, Scala resorts to providing you type information so you can ask such questions.

Comment: @jwvh yes, you are right, it suffers instead of "uses" type erasure and implicits can not affect the type erasure. But that's not what I am asking, I mean in some cases, implicits could be used instead of TypeTag, and why and what is the benefit to use TypeTag?

Comment: When you use type parameter (doesn't matter implicit or not) Scala compiler makes a decision regarding the type and it might be wrong as at run-time it might be not possible to infere the correct type. 
Using TypeTag it's possible to resolve this issue.

Comment: @LeylaLee; I challenge you to come up with A) code that demonstrates type erasure (neither of the posted examples does so) and B) an implicit parameter that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. `TypeTag`s are nearly always used *as* implicit parameters. If you aren't aware, `getKindName[T: TypeTag]` means `getKindName[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T])`.
   The exception would be when you store a `TypeTag` which you got as an implicit parameter somewhere. So "implicit parameters *vs* `TypeTag`" doesn't make sense to begin with.
2. The two snippets do not behave at all similarly, so they can't be solving the same problem, whatever that problem is. E.g. you can define

   ```
   implicit val x: Animal = new People
   getKindName1[Sparrow] // returns "Mammals"
   ```

   or without any extra implicits being defined, `getKindName1[Sparrow]` will not compile at all (and it isn't clear why you would have e.g. an implicit `Sparrow` in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I don't think are some points that I don't agree.
I don't think it will return "Mammals", it should return something like `cannot find implicit value for parameter x`

Comment: In this example, it returns a string of kind according to the animal class that it receives, however, because of the type erasure, it will lose the type information, no? I think implicit paramters could keep the type information. So I would like to know why use type Tag if an implicit paramter is already enough

Comment: "it returns a string of kind according to the animal class that it receives" No. It returns according to the value it receives. If `Sparrow` extends `Animal`, `x` will be found when searching for an implicit `Sparrow`, and the match  will return `"Mammals"` because the _value_ of `x` is an instance of `People`.

Comment: maybe you missed this ? def getKindName[T]`(implicit x: T)`